# RestTemplate to NOT escape url

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I'm using Spring RestTemplate successfully like this:

```java
String url = "http://example.com/path/to/my/thing/{parameter}";
ResponseEntity<MyClass> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, payload, MyClass.class, parameter);
```

And that is good.

However, sometimes `parameter` is `%2F`. I know this isn't ideal, but it is what it is.  The correct URL should be: `http://example.com/path/to/my/thing/%2F` but when I set `parameter` to `"%2F"` it gets double escaped to `http://example.com/path/to/my/thing/%252F`. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Instead of using a `String` URL, build a `URI` with a `UriComponentsBuilder`.

```
String url = "http://example.com/path/to/my/thing/";
String parameter = "%2F";
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url).path(parameter);
UriComponents components = builder.build(true);
URI uri = components.toUri();
System.out.println(uri); // prints "http://example.com/path/to/my/thing/%2F"
```

Use [`UriComponentsBuilder#build(boolean)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#build-boolean-) to indicate

> whether all the components set in this builder are **encoded (`true`)** or not (`false`)

This is more or less equivalent to replacing `{parameter}` and creating a `URI` object yourself.

```
String url = "http://example.com/path/to/my/thing/{parameter}";
url = url.replace("{parameter}", "%2F");
URI uri = new URI(url);
System.out.println(uri);
```

You can then use this `URI` object as the first argument to the `postForObject` method.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up solving this a little bit differently. In real life, my URL looks more like `http://example.com/path/{param}/to/place` so I did `UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url.replace("{param}", parameter))`.

Comment: I found it better to use `UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString()` instead of `fromHttpUrl()` because it allows URIs in the form of `/path/without/host` which is useful when testing with Spring `MockMvc`.

Comment: Why is this not a bug? It should be at least documented in the Javadoc.

Comment: @GeorgeSofianos It's documented in a **Note** in the `RestTemplate` javadoc, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). Template parameters are assumed to need encoding.

Answer (score 12):

You can tell the rest template that you have already encoded the uri. This can be done using UriComponentsBuilder.build(true). This way rest template will not reattempt to escape the uri. Most of the rest template api's will accept a URI as the first argument.

```
String url = "http://example.com/path/to/my/thing/{parameter}";
url = url.replace("{parameter}", "%2F");
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);
// Indicate that the components are already escaped
URI uri = builder.build(true).toUri();
ResponseEntity<MyClass> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, payload, MyClass.class, parameter);
```