# RestTemplate URL encoding

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I am trying to make a request as below

http://www.google.com/query?type=dvSwitch&format=records&fields=moref,name,vc,vcName&pageSize=10&filter=((isVMware==true,moref==dvs-59);isVCEnabled==true)

When i make this request on browser, browser doesn't encode any character in the url.

[image]

But when i try to make the same request with RestTemplate, it encodes = character to %3D.

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.exchange("http://www.google.com/query?type=dvSwitch&format=records&fields=moref,name,vc,vcName&pageSize=10&filter=((isVMware==true,moref==dvs-59);isVCEnabled==true)", HttpMethod.GET,null,String.class );
```

It converts the url to below format:

http://www.google.com/query?type=dvSwitch&format=records&fields=moref,name,vc,vcName&pageSize=10&filter=((isVMware%3D%3Dtrue,moref%3D%3Ddvs-59);isVCEnabled%3D%3Dtrue)

I want to make request without query parameters being encoded like that because this prevents endpoint working right.

How can make RestTemplate stop encoding query parameters?

Comment: When you make your request with RestTemplate, are you just passing in the whole url, or are you actually using query parameters?  It would be nice to see how you are making the call in your actual code...

Comment: You can't / shouldn't, because equals characters (`=`) are supposed to be escaped as `%3D`, and the server is required to unescape them. A URL with `=` in a query parameter value is invalid. `RestTemplate` is doing the right thing, and you're not when you paste into the browser. If the server cannot handle the escaping, then the server is buggy and should be fixed.

Comment: @hooknc I am using the code in the question. I am giving the whole url.

Comment: @Andreas Actually the endpoint is VCloud API. And it returns an error when i go with the encoded url.

Comment: @Andreas if it is wrong why browser doesn't need to encode it? It encodes some characters like ü,ş,ö,ç but not the  = character.

Comment: Try to make the call using UriComponentsBuilder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182836/resttemplate-to-not-escape-url

Comment: Riffing off of Jaime S' comment:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25434451/42962

Comment: The URL standard specifies that *all* characters not specific to the URL structure can be %-encoded. If a server doesn't handle that, the server is flawed. E.g. the URL for this page is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627111/resttemplate-url-encoding, but can be specified as https://%73%74%61%63%6B%6F%76%65%72%66%6C%6F%77%2E%63%6F%6D/%71%75%65%73%74%69%6F%6E%73/%34%38%36%32%37%31%31%31/%72%65%73%74%74%65%6D%70%6C%61%74%65%2D%75%72%6C%2D%65%6E%63%6F%64%69%6E%67. Try it in a browser. It works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RestTemplate to NOT escape url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182836/resttemplate-to-not-escape-url)