# how to escape, escape character('\') backslash in java microservices

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using microservices using spring boot in my application,
I use RestTemplate to call other component services from "org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate".
I have a common service from my component which calls other components to fetch data.

Whenever my search text has a backslash like "test\" my API call fails.
After debugging I came to the conclusion that till restTemplete.exchange API is not failing and I am not getting any requests in other component API methods.

```
// restTemplete.exchange(serviceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, responseType);
```

If I put 'text\t' API call is successful and control is reaching the other component
not sure if I am missing anything on this.
How do I escape the escape character?

I have tried `text.replace("\\", "\\\\");`, but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called UriComponentsBuilder.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28183190/8278152

Building your url using above component should help you.

Comment: i am already using UriComponentsBuilder for serviceUrl , the issue is with request body, not sure how to handle this.

Answer (score -2):

The better approach to utilize the REST API's of the microservices, registered under the same architecture, is to use Feign Client. For more details click [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html)

Comment: i cannot change this to Feign Client.

Comment: It does not solve the problem in question, Abdul. Why Faign is better in this case?